# 11 LEFT JOIN s make query very slow

Tags: mysql, join

I have  this  big  query it  contain  11 LEFT  JOINS  .  when  i run  it.  it get  **12s**  to  return  result  .  is  some  one  can assist me to  make  speed this  query  that big  help.  um  new  to  sql  code.  i  attache  image   of EXPLAIN   result

```
SELECT `idclients`, `clientsNameFirst`, `clientsNameLast`, `clientsEmail`, `clientsTelNoPersonalMobile`
FROM `clients`
LEFT JOIN `experienced` ON `experienced`.`clients_idclients` = `clients`.`idclients`
LEFT JOIN `designation` ON `designation`.`iddesignation` = `experienced`.`designation_iddesignation`
LEFT JOIN `industry` ON `industry`.`idindustry` = `experienced`.`industry_idindustry`
LEFT JOIN `company` ON `company`.`idcompany` = `experienced`.`company_idcompany`
LEFT JOIN `job_category` ON `job_category`.`idjobCategory`=`experienced`.`job_category_idjobCategory`
LEFT JOIN `academic_qualifications` ON `academic_qualifications`.`clients_idclients` = `clients`.`idclients`
LEFT JOIN `qulification` ON `qulification`.`idqulification` = `academic_qualifications`.`qulification_idqulification`
LEFT JOIN `institute` ON `institute`.`idinstitute` = `academic_qualifications`.`institute_idinstitute`
LEFT JOIN `client_tag` ON `client_tag`.`clients_idclients` = `clients`.`idclients`
LEFT JOIN `tag` ON `tag`.`idtag` = `client_tag`.`tag_idtag`
LEFT JOIN `cv` ON `cv`.`clients_idclients` = `clients`.`idclients`
WHERE (   `clients`.`fullName` LIKE '%Anti money laundering executive%' 
       OR `clients`.`clientsEmail` LIKE '%Anti money laundering executive%' 
       OR `clients`.`clientsTelNoPersonalMobile` LIKE '%Anti money laundering executive%' 
       OR `designation`.`designationName` LIKE '%Anti money laundering executive%' 
       OR `cv`.`cvName` LIKE '%Anti money laundering executive%' 
       OR `industry`.`industryName` LIKE '%Anti money laundering executive%' 
       OR `company`.`companyName` LIKE '%Anti money laundering executive%' 
       OR `qulification`.`qulificationName` LIKE '%Anti money laundering executive%' 
       OR `institute`.`instituteName` LIKE '%Anti money laundering executive%' 
       OR `job_category`.`jobCategoryName` LIKE '%Anti money laundering executive%' 
       OR `tag`.`tagName` LIKE '%Anti money laundering executive%' )
AND `clients`.`status_idstatus` != '10'
AND `clients`.`clientsAge` >= '0'
AND `clients`.`clientsAge` <= '100'
AND `clients`.`clientsOtherQualifications` = '1'
GROUP BY `clients`.`idclients`
ORDER BY `clients`.`idclients` DESC
 LIMIT 30
```

after  run  this  code  with   EXPLAIN   i got  this  result.
[image]

AND  this  is  my  db

[image]

This  is  my client  table stretcher

[image]

Comment: Is there a clustered index on clients.clientsid ? It would help the group by.

Comment: @Milan good  sir   um new  to SQL what  you  mean   by `clustered index` ??

Comment: Could you give us structure of clients table?

Comment: @Milan sir  i add   my client  table stretcher

Comment: Query can't be fast with [lot of] `%LIKE%`s as far as indexes are useless.

Comment: @Kondybas Good  sir  what i need to  do to  that  issue??

Comment: This is common side-effect of the indexing. Only `LIKE%` comparisons can be speeded up by indexes but not `%LIKE` or `%LIKE%` ones. Those latter two should be used as last resort only, not systematically. Also my strong advise is to switch your tables to the `utf8-general-ci` or `utf8-bin` to avoid future problems with national/diacritic symbols. Keep in mind that multitable queries can't use indexes for literal columns if they are in the different collations.

Comment: `latin1` will suffice for Western languages; utf8mb4 should be used if going global.

Comment: @Kondybas: not *quite* useless: an index scan+row lookup will usually be faster than a table scan.  Your broader point, that `LIKE '%ABC'` predicates are SARGable, is of course correct.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Solution part one:**

First of all, do not write numeric values as strings (avoid conversion). This is what these three lines should be:

```
AND `clients`.`status_idstatus` != 10
AND `clients`.`clientsAge` >= 0
AND `clients`.`clientsAge` <= 100
AND `clients`.`clientsOtherQualifications` = 1
```

**2. Solution part two:**

Second, try to make your query SARGable, so that it can use indexes and be faster.
(read more here: [What makes a SQL statement sargable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) )

Instead of using a non-SARGable argument, try to search like this:

```
WHERE (   `clients`.`fullName` LIKE 'Anti money laundering executive%' 
   OR `clients`.`clientsEmail` LIKE 'Anti money laundering executive%' 
   OR `clients`.`clientsTelNoPersonalMobile` LIKE 'Anti money laundering executive%' 
   OR `designation`.`designationName` LIKE 'Anti money laundering executive%' 
   OR `cv`.`cvName` LIKE 'Anti money laundering executive%' 
   OR `industry`.`industryName` LIKE 'Anti money laundering executive%' 
   OR `company`.`companyName` LIKE 'Anti money laundering executive%' 
   OR `qulification`.`qulificationName` LIKE 'Anti money laundering executive%' 
   OR `institute`.`instituteName` LIKE 'Anti money laundering executive%' 
   OR `job_category`.`jobCategoryName` LIKE 'Anti money laundering executive%' 
   OR `tag`.`tagName` LIKE 'Anti money laundering executive%' )
```

Comment: `int = '123'` is not a problem; the other way - `char = 123` is a big problem.

Comment: Part two is useless because (1) OP probably wants the string to be anywhere in the text, and (2) `ORs` and multiple table eliminate most changes of effective use of indexes, even if sargable.

Comment: Good  sir  thanks  for  you  help  i will try and  let  you know

Answer (score 1):

Start over.

Build a table of all the strings in a *single* `TEXT` column.  Use a `FULLTEXT` index on it.  Let that be the search table.  After finding `id` from that table, *then* do look up just those ids and do the `JOINs` without the `LIKEs`.

```
CREATE TABLE Search (
    idclient INT NOT NULL,      -- for JOINing to clients.idclient
    stuff MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,  -- all the strings collected together
    PRIMARY KEY(idclient),
    FULLTEXT(stuff)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

SELECT ...
    FROM Search AS s
    JOIN client AS c USING(idclient)
    LEFT JOIN ... -- without the LIKE
    WHERE MATCH(s.stuff) AGAINST('+Anti +money +laundering +executive' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
      AND c.status_idstatus...
      AND ...
```

The `MATCH` will take charge and whittle down the rows to very few, thereby making the rest of the query run fast.

There are 3 things conspiring to make you query slow:

- OR -- makes indexing useless
- Leading wildcards in `LIKE` -- making indexing useless
- Scattering all the strings across multiple tables -- requiring going off to all of them without knowing if there is anything useful there.

That is, the `LEFT JOIN` (contrary to what the titles suggests) is not the primary villain.

It might also be better to remove the Age test (etc) when they are not applicable.

Comment: Good  sir  thanks  for  you  help  i will try and  let  you know