# is xampp slow in windows server 2016?

Tags: mysql, windows-server

I have this  big query and  i run it  in  my  local  PC (Windows  10) and it  return  result  in **3s** but  i run  it in  client **Windows  2016 Server**  it get  more  time  than  **30s**

i  use  XAMPP in  both environment. if anyone can explain to me  what could be the problem here it's big help.
Thanks

```
SELECT `idclients`, 
       `clientsnamefirst`, 
       `clientsnamelast`, 
       `clientsemail`, 
       `clientstelnopersonalmobile` 
FROM   `clients` 
       LEFT JOIN `experienced` 
              ON `experienced`.`clients_idclients` = `clients`.`idclients` 
       LEFT JOIN `designation` 
              ON `designation`.`iddesignation` = 
                 `experienced`.`designation_iddesignation` 
       LEFT JOIN `industry` 
              ON `industry`.`idindustry` = `experienced`.`industry_idindustry` 
       LEFT JOIN `company` 
              ON `company`.`idcompany` = `experienced`.`company_idcompany` 
       LEFT JOIN `job_category` 
              ON `job_category`.`idjobcategory` = 
                 `experienced`.`job_category_idjobcategory` 
       LEFT JOIN `academic_qualifications` 
              ON `academic_qualifications`.`clients_idclients` = 
                 `clients`.`idclients` 
       LEFT JOIN `qulification` 
              ON `qulification`.`idqulification` = 
                 `academic_qualifications`.`qulification_idqulification` 
       LEFT JOIN `institute` 
              ON `institute`.`idinstitute` = 
                 `academic_qualifications`.`institute_idinstitute` 
WHERE  ( `clients`.`fullname` LIKE '%Senior Accountant%' 
          OR `clients`.`clientsemail` LIKE '%Senior Accountant%' 
          OR `clients`.`clientstelnopersonalmobile` LIKE '%Senior Accountant%' 
          OR `designation`.`designationname` LIKE '%Senior Accountant%' 
          OR `industry`.`industryname` LIKE '%Senior Accountant%' 
          OR `company`.`companyname` LIKE '%Senior Accountant%' 
          OR `qulification`.`qulificationname` LIKE '$Senior Accountant%' 
          OR `institute`.`institutename` LIKE '%Senior Accountant%' 
          OR `job_category`.`jobcategoryname` LIKE '%Senior Accountant%' ) 
       AND `clients`.`status_idstatus` != '10' 
       AND `clients`.`clientsotherqualifications` = '1' 
GROUP  BY `clients`.`idclients` 
ORDER  BY `clients`.`idclients` DESC 
LIMIT  30
```

Comment: What does a explain on both platforms show?

Comment: Related question:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213069/11-left-join-s-make-query-very-slow

Comment: 30s vs 3s -- Smells like things were cached on the less busy machine and the cache had been lost on the busy machine.

Answer (score 0):

There are a great many things that could affect the performance here:

1. Do both systems have the same data (or at least data of the same scale)?
2. What is the hardware environment of the two systems? *There is likely to be much more different than just the OS version.* More/less RAM, different IO subsystems, perhaps the client machine is using a shared SAN for storage not local drives (so there may be extra IO contention if that is overloaded), the client system could be running in a VM on a busy host (or a VM with specifically limited allocation of resources like io & cpu time)), ...
3. Check the output of `EXPLAIN <query>` on both systems to see if they are processing the query differently. Include the plans this outputs in your question too as the information may be useful to people helping you. If the plans differ it could be because of schema differences (are there indexes missing in one location for instance or database configuration (how much memory it can use particularly).
4. How the DB server is configured can have a significant effect too, has this been tuned at all or are they using defaults. Don't expect this to be exactly the same as your config though: due to all the potential environment differences what is optimal for your dev box may not be optimal for the other server.

To answer the specific question as well as we can without much extra information:

> is xampp slow in windows server 2016?

No. There is no reason to expect it to be slower on that OS compared to Windows 10 *if the rest of the environment is the same*.

Comment: @redhat In your original question, please post TEXT results of EXPLAIN <query> and identify which platform the EXPLAIN came from.